# Android layout for define screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout

in my app i have activity with XML layout, i want to build an special XML layout for screen that is 3.14 in. , and if someone will install the app on an device with 3.14 in. device so the activity will use the new XML.

i want to know if there is a way to do it with eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the screen resolution and denisty, lets say 320x480 and MDPI. Create a folder in

> /res

named

> /layout-mdpi-320x480

and put your XML files in there. You can change the resolution and density (hdpi, ldpi, nodpi etc...) I don't think you can do it with the screen size.

Comment: and how i can know the density?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the standard mechanism which zeokila pointed out.
However, the result is rather coarse.

When you want a very dedicated match, you could check all parameter in activities onCreate and switch explicitly between diffent layouts for setContent